# FTP Quote command using CFTPClient library

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange

By searching on internet for `Quote` command did not find much.

I am using CFTPClient library from
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8667/FTP-Client-Class

How to send `QUOTE` command after copying a file to FTP?

```
Quote rcmd sbmjob cmd(call pgm...
```

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `QUOTE` command in FTP *protocol*.

The `quote` is a common command in many command-line FTP *clients* (like the Windows `ftp.exe` or the Linux `ftp`) that sends an arbitrary FTP *protocol* command to the FTP server.

So the actual *protocol* command you want to send to the FTP server is `RCMD`. *(Though note that `RCMD` is not a standard FTP protocol command, it seems to be a [server-specific command of IBM AS/400 FTP server](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/latest?topic=ssw_ibm_i_75/rzaiq/rzaiqrcmd.htm)).*

The `CFTPClient` does not support the `RCMD`, nor it seems to support sending an arbitrary command to the server (what is otherwise common in FTP client libraries).

But if you take a look at the implementation of the `CFTPClient::SendCommand`, you will see how to implement it on your own.

It would be like:

```c
m_apSckControlConnection->Write("RCMD sbmjob ...", length, ...);
CReply reply;
GetResponse(reply);
```